# How to get relative path instead of fake path in fileInput in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Using fileInput I load files into the UI. I need what's the relative path of the file. In uploadFile(event) method,

```
uploadFile(event){
  console.log(event.value);
}
```

But this file path get as below,

"C:\fakePath\fileName"

I need a full path instead of a fake path. How I get the full path?

### HTML

```
<input hidden type="file" #fileInput (click)="fileInput.value = null" (change)="uploadFile($event.target)" multiple>
```

Comment: It's not possible as it could lead to security issues .

Comment: Relative to what? Your server?

Comment: No In my computer. Get real path as a Example:   "C:/Users/Desktop/fileName"